# Moderate users homedirs - removing cleartext passwords

Tags: shell-script, users, password

On one of Linux terminals I administrate, we allow users to write own scripts in bash/perl/python to enhance their administrative tasks. The problem with users is they don't always follow the rules.

One of the rules is that their code is not allowed to have clear-text passwords hardcoded. You can guess that not all follow.
What is the best way to enforce this policy on users/homedirs etc?

Answer (score 3):

This isn't something you can really control without extremely intrusive testing.  You could conceivably attempt to log in as a user with every string you find in their home directory (and sanction the user if you're ever successful), but that's far from reasonable or feasible.  You could, though, if this is for secure shell connections, disable password authentication entirely in `sshd_config` and require all users to set up public/private key pairs.